# Reset iPad mini forgotten Apple ID

Tags: ios, ipad, apple-id, internet

I wanted to know if there is a way to reset my son's iPad mini, because he forgot the Apple ID password. He accidentally reformat, and now, he doesn't know the password.

Comment: Start at https://iforgot.apple.com

Answer (score -1):

Try resetting on iOS then create new apple I.D. Use an email address and use a different password.

Comment: (I've had the same problem before.)

Comment: & have to buy all your apps again… lose your old photos...

Comment: I know. It's a nightmare.